# <a href> get value in php

Tags: php, html, href

The current page someone is in on my website is highlighted on the navigation menu (the class `"active"`). I've done this through php, which compares the current page to a `string`. I'd like to simplify it even further because **this string is actually the href value of the menu item**.

Is there a way to get the `href` value of this item via php? That way I could just use that variable instead.

My php code:

```
<?php
function curPageName()
{
    return substr($_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"], strrpos($_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"], "/") + 1);
}
function activeMenuItem($href)
{
    return (curPageName() == $href) ? "class=\"active\"" : "";
}
?>
```

and the html in the body:

```
<ul id="navilist">
    <li><a href="index.php" <?php echo activeMenuItem('index.php'); ?>>Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="resume.php" <?php echo activeMenuItem('resume.php'); ?>>Resume</a></li>
    <li><a href="projects.php" <?php echo activeMenuItem('projects.php'); ?>>Projects</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.php" <?php echo activeMenuItem('contact.php'); ?>>Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm

Comment: I don't recommend parsing the output of the script just to read the href value...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Build your menu in a loop:

```
$menu_items = array(
    'Home' => 'index.php',
    'Resume' => 'resume.php'
);

<ul id="navilist">
    <?php foreach ( $menu_items as $title => $href ): ?>
        <li><a href="<?php echo $href; ?>" <?php echo activeMenuItem($href); ?>>
            <?php echo $title; ?>
        </a></li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: Same as previous answer + I really like your suggestion! +1

Answer (score 1):

You Can't get the href value using php code.

in my knowledge - one way to get the href value

You should declare the page name with one one variable like

```
$home="home.php";
$resume="resume.php";
.
.
.



<ul id="navilist">
    <li><a href="<?php echo $home;?>" <?php echo activeMenuItem($home); ?>>Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="<?php echo $resume;?>" <?php echo activeMenuItem($resume); ?>>Resume</a></li>
    .
    .
    .
</ul>
```

I am not sure. Please check it.

Comment: This suits me just fine! I feel stupid not thinking about this!